# Blank Option Text using $(dropdown).append(new Option("Joe Blow", 1, true, true) in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code works correctly in both Chrome and Firefox.  In IE 9 the options are appended, but the Text is always blank.

```
function populateDeveloperDropDownViaSkillProfileSpecificAjaxcall(dropdown, selectedProfileId, selectedDeveloperId) 
{
    $(dropdown).prepend("<option value=''></option>");
    $.getJSON(ajaxActionToGetFilteredDeveloperList, { skillProfileId: selectedProfileId, "selectedDeveloperId": selectedDeveloperId },
        function (data) {
            var opt;
            //Returns a List of ASP.NET MVC SelectListItem serialized to JSON
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                if (v != undefined && v.Selected == true) {
                    opt = new Option(v.Text, v.Value, true, true);
                }
                else {
                    opt = new Option(v.Text, v.Value);
                }
                $(dropdown).append(opt);
            });

        }
    );
}
```

Does anybody see something that I'm doing wrong or have a work-around for this?   Apologies if this is a dumb error, but I've spent several hours on it and I'm just banging my head at this point.

Comment: take a look at the response that you receive from the server using the debugger and make sure that IE is not throwing an exception

Comment: OT: You spelled "filtered" wrong in `ajaxActionToGetFileteredDeveloperList` or perhaps you meant "filleted developer list" (which is sometimes a reasonable sentiment).

Comment: I've tried stepping through it with VS attached as the Debugger - no exceptions seems to be thrown (although debugging JS is a bit foreign to me).   I also tried it in IE with the F12 Dev tools.  I turned on the IE status bar to see if any errors were displayed - nothing there.   Looking at the request/response with Fiddler things look good too.   Is there anything like Firefox's tools>Error Console in IE?

Comment: mu is too short: thanks.  I fixed the typo.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to a weird issue affecting past IE versions; to overcome it, I would try to force IE to update the option text after it has been appended:

```
if (v != undefined && v.Selected == true) {
    opt = new Option(v.Text, v.Value, true, true);
}
else {
    opt = new Option(v.Text, v.Value);
}

$(dropdown).append(opt);
$(opt).text(v.Text);
```

I don't know if this is the cause of your issue or not, but it is better to try.