# jQuery val() not working in IE for dynamically added option

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am generating options for my dropdown by jQuery ajax method, filling it by db.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + '/FillAssignee',
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                            $('#SelectAssignee').append($("<option></option>").val(response.d[i]['Value']).html(response.d[i]['Text']));
                        }
                        if (response.d.length > 0) 
                        {
                          $('#SelectAssignee>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true); 
                          alert($('#SelectAssignee').val()); //this line giving me correct value but value not showing in dropdown as selected in ie
                        }
                  }            
      });
```

It's works fine. only problem is that first value not got selected by default on IE. So for that I used many options

```
1. $('#SelectAssignee').val();
2. $('#SelectAssignee option:first').attr('selected','selected');
3. $('#SelectAssignee option:first').prop('selected',true);
```

How can I get it work?

Comment: Try adding a `.trigger('change')` after you set the `selected` property

Comment: @Abhilash thanks for your response but not working for me.

Comment: Is that loop of yours in your ajax succes call back?

Comment: @techie_28 yes i am applying this loop in success callback of my jquery ajax method

Comment: Typically for setting an option display text, I have always used `.text()` rather than the `.html()` method. May not make any difference, but worth a shot to try `.text()` when you are creating the `option`s.

Comment: $("<option></option>").val(response.d[i]['Value']).html(response.d[i]['Text']).attr({'selected' : true}); have you tried this?

Comment: Your code should actually work. Created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmz9X/) that mimics the same (some parts are slightly different in methods/selectors, but that shouldn't matter). Tested and working in IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Have you tested with jquery `.live()` function, Some times jquery can't directly access values of dropdown that are dynamically generated,

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 var selObj = document.getElementById('SelectAssignee');
 selObj.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: +1. It's a known fact that IE prefers manipulating the `options` property rather than creating `<option>` nodes and adding those, so this has a pretty high chance of working :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is saying that you are targeting the FIRST element in your select menu, however, you are adding the new option to the END of the select input. You either need to change your .append to .prepend, or target the last option when setting the selected attribute to true

Answer (score 0):

Try setting as attributes rather than properties.

```
$('#SelectAssignee').append($("<option />", { value: response.d[i]['Value'], html: response.d[i]['Text'] }));
```

Comment: @rahul, Can I see this issue some how? May be like a fiddle.

Comment: it's filling from db so not possible to make a fiddle for that

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below solution.

After the for loop, just add this

```
if (response.d.length > 0) {
   $('#SelectAssignee>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
}
```

Comment: what is the value that you are getting for $('#SelectAssignee>option:eq(1)').val()

Comment: it giving me the correct value on alert but not setting it as selected

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of IE are you using.

Comment: Currently which value is getting selected by default? Is it the last appended value??

Comment: this issue is related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304049/blank-option-text-using-dropdown-appendnew-optionjoe-blow-1-true-true but ans given in this post also not working for me.

Comment: Could you please post the modified function. updated with            if (response.d.length > 0) {
   $('#SelectAssignee>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
}

Comment: I think something else is creating the issue. When I tested, it was working in IE8 and FF.

Comment: i am also thinking the same thing because this code not working on page load but if i will set dropdown value on some other event it's working fine

Comment: On which event you are trying to dynamically load the dropdownlist?

Comment: I have tested this in document.ready function and it was working.

Comment: Are you calling any other method after this json call?

Comment: no there is nothing that can change it's value and it's giving me correct value if i alert it after setting it as selected. but not showing it as selected

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this should work. Although, this seems like a dirty hack, there was an occasion when I had to resort to this and it worked.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $('#SelectAssignee option:first').prop('selected', true);
    $('#SelectAssignee').trigger('change');
}, 1000 );
```

Try putting this code block in the success callback, after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop, try following condition

```
if (response.d.length > 0) { $('#SelectAssignee>option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value explicitly to the value of the first option

```
$('#SelectAssignee').val(response.d[0]['Value']);
```